# How to ugrade pdfsam?

Tags: 12.04, pdf

How to upgrade pdfsam from 1.1.4-1 version included in ubuntu sofware center to 2.2.1 version, either the basic or enhanced version, in Ubuntu 12.04?

I only found a possible solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9109328&postcount=5) but it is for ubuntu 9.10 and the file system is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [PDFsam Zip archive](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=32), extract it wherever you want, make the jar-file executable and then start it.

**Or**

Open a terminal and paste the following commands.

```
wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pdfsam/pdfsam/2.2.1/pdfsam-2.2.1-out.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pdfsam.org%2F%3Fpage_id%3D32&ts=1347454695&use_mirror=freefr'
unzip -d pdfsam pdfsam-2.2.1-out.zip\?r=http:%2F%2Fwww.pdfsam.org%2F\?page_id=32\&ts=1347454695\&use_mirror=freefr
cd pdfsam
java -jar pdfsam-2.2.1.jar
```

Comment: thanks! I was too dizzy and have downloaded source files before... Just for the sake of completeness, I right-click jar file and then I open it with openJDK.

Answer (score 2):

you can download it from this link : http://www.practicatechnical.com/files/pdfsam_2.2.1.deb

and from the downloaded directory you can install with

```
sudo dpkg -i pdfsam_2.2.1.deb
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: thank you. I tried it but there are dependency problems like libdom4j-java and others. I do not think they will fit here :)

Comment: @user81022 you can do sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: you've done magic (or I am getting old), it is OK now

Answer (score 0):

The file from my website is listed above. I've just posted a slightly newer one:
http://www.practicatechnical.com/files/pdfsam_2.2.2_all.deb